# What is the best solution to prevent malicious IPs from accessing my hosting server?

Tags: ip, hosting, shared-hosting

Just to explain my setup: I have a few websites hosted on a shared server (Lunarpages) and I use Google Apps (with modified MX records in Lunarpages) so the Google Apps emails work.

Now, I've noticed occationally that a mail script on one of my sites gets triggered without any content, though it includes IP information that the form collects. I looked up a couple of those IP address with AbuseIPDB, and they are known hacking IPs. So I want a good way to block all access to my server from known bad IPs.

I see in Cpanel in Lunarpages an option to turn on CloudFlare for security, and looking into them a little, it does appear that they block bad IPs. But I'm a little concerned about whether that would risk messing up how my site works or email works or how my analytics and email forms collect IP address information or if there would be anything different from me besides just turning it on and that the bad IPs would be blocked. I'm not looking to get myself in to a lot of troubleshooting.

Is CloudFlare a good solution, or are there other good alternatives?

Regarding the AbuseIPDB, they look like they have an API that I might be able to set up to block IPs, but if I understand right, I would have to modify all my sites and that still wouldn't block direct access to a lot of files. Unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ipset to block a list of IP addresses and you can  set up ipset list of IP addresses from some spam DB.